# Permanent URLs of images from S3 without showing the path of image in S3 bucket

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3-bucket

I am new to AWS S3 Service and working on a project like Dropbox. Now I want to store all the images in S3 with PHP and currently, I am using S3 presigned URL to PUT Image. Now I want to show the Image to the users. I found 2 ways to do this:

1. Give the public access to S3 Bucket (Which I don't want to do that).
2. Presigned URLs for GET object. (but user can view the directory structure)

I want something like permanent URLs to view image and but without showing the path of the image as it is in S3 Bucket. For example, currently the URL has the structure like this :

domain.com///?

but I want something like this:

domain.com/ **some code** is like a pointer to get the image from s3 bucket's directory. Please give me a hint to do so.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like you will need to write a web server that delivers images based on a token defined by you.

Comment: yes something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this script as a proxy to fetch the image from S3 using php curl.

```
$bucket = 'bucketname';
$filename = 'somefile.jpg';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://s3-<region>.amazonaws.com/' . $bucket . '/' . $filename);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

header("Content-Length: " . strlen($data));
echo $data;
```

Combine with .htaccess `RewriteRule` for example, then your s3 bucket url is hidden and can simply fetch resource such as this url `http://example.com/resources/images/somefile.jpg`

```
RewriteRule ^resources/images/([^/]+)$ /proxy.php?filename=$1 [QSA,L]
```